# AngularJS Force Model To Update From Angular Ui TypeAhead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

so I have an [Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) Typeahead that is working, however I have a use case that I can't get it to cooperate with.

My issue is getting it to display a certain value based not on user-input, which works, but based on the state.

I'm using [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), so my code looks like this:

```
if($stateParams.assetID != undefined)
  {
    $http.get('/getData/idRepo', {
      params: {
        id: $stateParams.assetID
      }
    }).then(function(response){
        $scope.getMaterial(response.data[0].Title);
        //this is where I try and trigger the getMaterial 
        //function to show the Typeahead value based on a url parameter
        //
    });
  }

$scope.getMaterial = function(val) {
    return $http.get($scope.material[0].Query, {
      params: {
        title: val
      }
    }).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

My Typeahead HTML is this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected.asyncSelected"
       placeholder="Material Name..." 
       uib-typeahead="med as med.name for med in getMaterial($viewValue)" 
       typeahead-editable="false"
       typeahead-template-url="meditationssearch.html" 
       typeahead-select-on-exact="true" 
       typeahead-select-on-exact="true" 
       typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
       typeahead-no-results="noResults"
       class="form-control">
```

As you can see, the typeahead reads from `getMaterial()` which I try to trigger in my `if($stateParams.assetID != undefined)` conditional.

**Expected workflow:**

1. Navigate to this view with a `$stateparam` for the `assetID` in the url.
2. Have the conditional see that `assetID` param is not undefined, fire the GET request and then have it return the results from the running `getMaterial()` (the result of the first GET request gets passed through getMaterial's() own GET request - as if the result of the first GET request were being typed in).
3. Update the model/typeahead to display `getMaterial()` value in the view.

I tried `$scope.$apply()` but the digest is already in progress. I'm hoping there is another quick fix that I'm just not aware of to trigger the typeahead.

I also tried something like this:

`jQuery("input[uib-typeahead]").val(response.data[0].Title).trigger('input');`

...but that isn't a good solution because some of the assets I am type-aheading for have the exact same name, which is why I'm trying to use the `id` as my url parameter and have the typeahead source function pick up the name as if it was typed in and then return to full object (name/id) to the model.

Please help me achieve my desired workflow.

**Edit:** [Typeahead Source Code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js):

I believe I want to activate something in the select function:

```
 scope.select = function(activeIdx, evt) {
      //called from within the $digest() cycle
      var locals = {};
      var model, item;

      selected = true;
      locals[parserResult.itemName] = item = scope.matches[activeIdx].model;
      model = parserResult.modelMapper(originalScope, locals);
      $setModelValue(originalScope, model);
      modelCtrl.$setValidity('editable', true);
      modelCtrl.$setValidity('parse', true);

      onSelectCallback(originalScope, {
        $item: item,
        $model: model,
        $label: parserResult.viewMapper(originalScope, locals),
        $event: evt
      });

      resetMatches();

      //return focus to the input element if a match was selected via a mouse click event
      // use timeout to avoid $rootScope:inprog error
      if (scope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadFocusOnSelect) !== false) {
        $timeout(function() { element[0].focus(); }, 0, false);
      }
    };
```

Maybe `resetMatches()`? How do I call that from my own controller?

Comment: The example code doesn't make sense. What is the URL that the `getMaterial` function use for its fetch? The code example uses `$scope.material[0].Query` but does not show how `$scope.material` is initialized.

Comment: @georgeawg it's just a variable URL that changes based on other conditions... by the time I want to run this code `$scope.material` is already dealt with..

Comment: `$scope.material` array conflicts with the iterator that the `uib-typeahead` directive uses.

Comment: @georgeawg Understood, I edited my code and question to change the `uib-typeahead` iterator.

Comment: @georgeawg Still have the same issue, however.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Another way to do it is to hook into the Typeahead itself, this way if it has the same name it will pick the right object for the model.

See here:

**https://plnkr.co/edit/ABM72yyV4dtp5PsH4bIm?p=preview**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http,uibTypeaheadParser) {

$scope.fire = function(val){
      var locals = {};
      var model;
      var parserResult = uibTypeaheadParser.parse(angular.element("input[uib-typeahead]")[0].getAttribute('uib-typeahead'));
      locals[parserResult.itemName] = val;
    model = parserResult.modelMapper($scope, locals);
    console.log(model);
    $scope.customSelected = model; //$scope.customSelected is the ng-model in this example
  }

  });
```

Where `val` is an object, rather than a string.

```
<button ng-click="fire({
  'name': 'Minnesota',
  'flag': 'b/b9/Flag_of_Minnesota.svg/46px-Flag_of_Minnesota.svg.png'
})" class="button btn-primary">CLICK ME TO SET TYPEAHEAD</button>
```

Comment: MIxing AngularJS and jQuery like that is asking for trouble.

Comment: @georgeawg If I make it into a custom directive and then hook into Typeahead in said directive's controller anyway, thereby removing the jQuery, will you remove your downvote? 

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to the previous approach I would share another solution where there is no need for a directive. You can just simply locate the input element and set the view value there.

> `angular.element('#input').controller('ngModel').$setViewValue('');`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `getMaterial($viewValue)` in the html (Which will fire every digest cycle...) you can wire up an ng-change instead and that way only fire when the data has actually changed. In that case you have a model `$scope.materials` now that you can update whenever you want to get the changes.

**javascript:**

```
$scope.modelChanged = function(){
    $http.get($scope.material[0].Query, {
        params: {
            title: $scope.selected.asyncSelected
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.materials = response.data;
    });
}

if ($stateParams.assetID != undefined) {
    $http.get('/getData/idRepo', {
        params: {
            id: $stateParams.assetID
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.selected.asyncSelected = response.data[0].Title;

        $scope.modelChanged(); //not sure if you have to run this it might fire automatically
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected.asyncSelected"
       placeholder="Material Name..." 
       uib-typeahead="material as material.name for material in materials" 
       typeahead-editable="false"
       typeahead-template-url="meditationssearch.html" 
       typeahead-select-on-exact="true" 
       typeahead-select-on-exact="true" 
       typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
       typeahead-no-results="noResults"
       ng-change="modelChanged()"
       class="form-control">
```

Comment: Your statement that the array expression is evaluated every digest cycle is erroneous. The `uib-typeahead` directive only evaluates the array expression when the user types a letter in the input (or pastes text to the input). The `uib-tyeahead` directive also accepts an array expression which returns a promise. For more information, see [UI-Bootstrap `uib-typeahead` Directive API Reference](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!typeahead).

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom directive:

```
app.directive("forceInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: postLink
  }
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    attrs.$observe('forceInput', function(value) {
      if (!value) return;
      elem[0].value = value;
      ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
    })
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected.asyncSelected"
       force-input="{{forceValue}}"
       placeholder="Material Name..." 
       uib-typeahead="med as med.name for med in getMaterial($viewValue)" 
       typeahead-editable="false"
       typeahead-template-url="meditationssearch.html" 
       typeahead-select-on-exact="true" 
       typeahead-select-on-exact="true" 
       typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
       typeahead-no-results="noResults"
       class="form-control">
```

JS

```
if($stateParams.assetID != undefined)
  {
    $http.get('/getData/idRepo', {
      params: {
        id: $stateParams.assetID
      }
    }).then(function(response){
        ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶g̶e̶t̶M̶a̶t̶e̶r̶i̶a̶l̶(̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶[̶0̶]̶.̶T̶i̶t̶l̶e̶)̶;̶
        $scope.forceValue = response.data[0].Title;
        //this is where I try and trigger the getMaterial 
        //function to show the Typeahead value based on a url parameter
        //
    });
  }
```

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/MOL19qyJtr5sr4s8u6Ds?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var _selected;

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
                   'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia',
                   'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas',
                   'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 
                   'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 
                   'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico',
                   'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma',
                   'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 
                   'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia',
                   'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
});

angular.module('app').directive("forceInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: postLink
  }
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    attrs.$observe('forceInput', function(value) {
      if (!value) return;
      elem[0].value = value;
      ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
    })
  }
})
```

```html
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <link href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body ng-app="app">

  <div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="ctrl">

    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected"
           force-input="a"
           uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
           class="form-control">

 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Won't work if you have two things with the same name which is always possible... see my answer I believe it works well.

Comment: What do you mean "two things with the same name"? Just change the scope name for the different inputs.

Comment: In your example if you have two states named "Alabama".

Comment: Also your answer doesn't select the desired input properly. Even if I enter in the exact name of one of the options, the typeahead is still not resolved.